# Difference between 'Aggregated self time' and 'Self time', 'Aggregated total time' and 'Total time' in Chrome CPU Profile of JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, profiling

What is the difference between the 'Aggregated self time' and 'Self time', 'Aggregated total time' and 'Total time' columns in the Chrome CPU profiling of JS code?

you can see in the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8nVx.png that **Self time** is bigger than **Aggregated self time**, and **Total time** is bigger than **Aggregated total time**, i do not know why.

i think **Aggregated self time** should be bigger than **Self time**, and **Aggregated total time** should be bigger than **Total time**.

i could not realy certain the words in the document below: 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/rendering-tools/js-execution?hl=en

> **Self time**. How long it took to complete the current invocation of the function, including only the statements in the function itself, not including any functions that it called.
>
> **Aggregated self time**. Aggregate time for all invocations of the function across the recording, not including functions called by this function.
>
> **Total time**. The time it took to complete the current invocation of this function and any functions that it called.
>
> **Aggregated total time**. Aggregate total time for all invocations of the function, including functions called by this function.

**it is the Chrome bug?** my Google Chrome version is **51.0.2704.106 m**

Comment: did you ever figure this out?